# Regular expression to match optional group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm expecting a string that may or may not have '#' followed by some numbers. If there's any numbers after '#' I want to capture it as second group, otherwise just capture everything in first group. Following is example for C#

> - `ABC#99999`//match Group1: ABC and Group2: 99999
> - `9ABC#8` //match Group1 9ABC and Group
> - `9ABC` //match Group1 9ABC
> - `9ABC#` //match Group1 9ABC#

The following Regex works, but for 3rd and 4th string, it captures into group 3 instead of group 1. is there a better way for the above scenario?

> (?:(.+)#(\d+))|(.+)

Alternatively, I came up with following Regex, but the problem is since the first group doesn't have a fixed format (like length), it captures whole string from 1st and second string instead of capturing 2 groups

> (.+)(?:#(\d+))?

Comment: So, you basically want to match a whole string, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, but if there are digits after '#', I need to capture them into two separate groups

Comment: Good, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343605/3832970) then. Please fix the expected results in the question as the requirements are out of sync with the examples.

Comment: @Praati I edited the 4th example output according to your comment to CertainPerformance's answer, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a whole string and place the part before an optional `#` + digits into Group 1 and all those digits into Group 2, you may use

```
^(.+?)(?:#(\d+))?$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28.%2B%3F%29%28%3F%3A%23%28%5Cd%2B%29%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=ABC%2399999%0D%0A9ABC%238%0D%0A9ABC%0D%0A9ABC%23&o=m). The `\r?` is added because it is a multiline input demo, you won't need it if you plan to test separate strings against the pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars as few as possible (due to `+?` lazy quantifier) (**NOTE** that if Group 1 value may be missing, use `(.*?)` instead)
- `(?:#(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `#` - a `#` symbol
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

[image]

Comment: I think you answered my question. I will test it and mark it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(\w+)(?:#(\d+))?
```

The `#` is in an optional non-capturing group, and the following digits in a captured group *inside* the non-capturing group.

https://regex101.com/r/obKPFw/1

Comment: That works but sorry, I need to capture 9ABC# in fourth example. I mistyped in my question, I apologize for that.

Comment: @Praati Please fix it in the question as the requirements are out of sync with the examples.

Comment: really dumb question, how do I edit my question. I went to my profile>question... don't see edit button

Comment: @Praati It's a button below the question itself, right below the tags.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, WITHOUT using regular expressions:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> inputs = new List<string>
        {
            "ABC#99999",
            "9ABC#8",
            "9ABC",
            "9ABC#"
        };

        var groups = new List<Group>();

        foreach (string input in inputs)
        {
            string[] parts = input.Split("#", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var group = new Group
            {
                Part1 = input
            };
            
            if (parts.Length == 2)
            {
                group.Part1 = parts[0];
                group.Part2 = parts[1];
            };

            groups.Add(group);

            Console.WriteLine($"Input: '{input}': {group}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Part1 { get; set; }
    public string Part2 { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Part1: {Part1 ?? "null"}, Part2: {Part2 ?? "[null]"}";
    }
}
```

Output:

> Input: 'ABC#99999': Part1: ABC, Part2: 99999
>
> Input: '9ABC#8': Part1: 9ABC, Part2: 8
>
> Input: '9ABC': Part1: 9ABC, Part2: [null]
>
> Input: '9ABC#': Part1: 9ABC#, Part2: [null]